# AWS Hive + Kinesis on EMR = Understanding check-pointing

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, emr, amazon-kinesis

I have an AWS Kinesis stream and I created an external table in Hive pointing at it. I then create a DynamoDB table for the checkpoints and in my Hive query I set the following properties as described [here:](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-kinesis-checkpoints.html)

```
set kinesis.checkpoint.enabled=true;
set kinesis.checkpoint.metastore.table.name=my_dynamodb_table;
set kinesis.checkpoint.metastore.hash.key.name=HashKey;                                                               
set kinesis.checkpoint.metastore.range.key.name=RangeKey;                                                            
set kinesis.checkpoint.logical.name=my_logical_name;                                                                 
set kinesis.checkpoint.iteration.no=0;
```

I have the following questions:

- Do I always have to start with `iteration.no` set to 0?
- Does this always start from the beginning of the script (oldest Kinesis record about to be evicted)?
- Imagine I set up a cron to schedule the execution of the script, how do I retrieve the 'next' iteration number?
- To re-execute the script on the same data, is it enough to re run the query with the same execution number?
- If I execute a `select * from kinesis_ext_table limit 100`with `iteration.no=0` over and over, will I get different/weird results once the first Kinesis records start to be evicted?

Given the DynamoDB checkpoint entry:

```
{"startSeqNo":"1234",
 "endSeqNo":"5678",
 "closed":false}
```

- What's the meaning of the `closed` field?
- Are sequence number incremental and is there a relation between the start and end (EG: end - start = number of records read)?
- I noticed that sometimes there is only the endSeqNum (no startSeqNum), how should I interpret that?

I know that it's a lot of questions but I could not find these answers on the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Kinesis documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/key-concepts.html) and the [Kinesis Storage Handler Readme](https://github.com/qubole/kinesis-storage-handler) which contains answers to many of your questions.

> Do I always have to start with iteration.no set to 0?

Yes, unless you are doing some advanced logic which requires you to skip a known or already processed part of the stream

> Does this always start from the beginning of the script (oldest
>   Kinesis record about to be evicted)?

Yes

> Imagine I set up a cron to schedule the execution of the script, how do I retrieve the 'next' iteration number?

This is handled by the hive script, since it is querying all data in the kinesis stream at each run

> To re-execute the script on the same data, is it enough to re run the query with the same execution number?

As Kinesis data is a 24-hour time window, the data has (possibly) changed since your last query, so you probably would want to query all records again in the Hive job

> If I execute a select * from kinesis_ext_table limit 100with iteration.no=0 over and over, will I get different/weird results once the first Kinesis records start to be evicted?

Yes, you would expect the results to change as the stream changes

> Given the DynamoDB checkpoint entry:
>   What's the meaning of the closed field?

Although this is an internal detail of the Kinesis Storage Handler, I believe this indicates whether the shard is a parent shard, which indicates whether is it open and accepting new data or closed and not accepting new data into the shard. If you have scaled your stream up or down, parent shards exist for 24 hours, and contain all data since you scaled, however no new data will be inserted into these shards.

> Are sequence number incremental and is there a relation between the start and end (EG: end - start = number of records read)?

New sequence numbers generally increase over time is the only guidance that Amazon provide on this.

> I noticed that sometimes there is only the endSeqNum (no startSeqNum), how should I interpret that?

This means the shard is open and still accepting new data (not a parent shard)